# What is Nerd Test all about?

Tags: phrases, expressions, colloquialisms

Not sure, where to ask this. I did it [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14537/what-is-nerd-test-all-about), and it was put in `Hold` , *finally* attempting here as a *last* try!! I am really curious(!) to know what is this?

I got this [link](http://www.nerdtests.com/ft_nq.php) randomly about how `nerd` are you. And nerd is *new* term to me, being interested clicked that link and it threw me a set of strange questions. Questions on periodic elements(!!).. etc.

Finally, after *honestly* answering, got this message..

> 30% scored higher (more nerdy), 2% scored the same, and 68% scored
>   lower (less nerdy).
>
> What does this mean? Your nerdiness is:
>
> Low Ranking Nerd. Definitely a nerd but low on the totem pole of
>   nerds.

Can someone hint me, what is this all about? I *really* googled a lot!

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerd

Comment: There's [this fascinating analysis](http://slackprop.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/on-geek-versus-nerd/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *nerd* has so many cultural connotations, both positive and negative, that you should read [the Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerd) to get a good understanding. Generally, it is used as a label for someone who:

- is highly intelligent and very knowledgeable about mathematics, science, and computers;
- is a fan of science fiction and/or similar pursuits (e.g., video games or anime), possibly to the point of dangerous obsession;
- has poorly developed social skills and is not very sexually or romantically experienced.

The word has historically been a pejorative, but over the past 20 years or so as the Internet has become a major part of modern life, many people have come to self-identify as nerds, even to embrace the term. In keeping with this recent evolution in usage, *nerd* is also used by extension to describe someone who is an enthusiast about a particular hobby or intellectual pursuit: *history nerd*, *classic car nerd*. These usages are usually not intended pejoratively, although they can be.

I would guess that the "nerd test" at the link you supplied was created by someone who considers themself a nerd, so that's an example of the word being used in a mostly non-pejorative way.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and what does the final line tells ? `Low Ranking..` . That's what pricking me!!

Comment: It means that, in the opinion of the test designer, you're not much of a nerd... which is nothing to be ashamed of.

Comment: ... especially since such tests are not intended to be taken at all seriously.

Comment: @keshlam :) I was not serious, but I didn't understand it.